# Remove namespace n tags using xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to remove two root tags and one namespace using xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sxi:Messages xmlns:sxi="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<sxi:Message1>
<ZDetails>
.
.
</ZDetails>
</sxi:Message1>
</sxi:Messages>
```

I want it to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZDetails>
..
.
</ZDetails>
```

No data in between tags  n  should be changed.. I tried joinin some xslt codes by searching but they are deleting some attributes in between ZDetails. So posting a new one. Can any one help me wit respective xslt code.

Comment: FYI, XSLT doesn't operate on tags at all. It only copies or constructs nodes (e.g. elements and attributes). The input nodes come from parsed tags and the output nodes get serialized as tags. Asking XSLT to remove tags is like saying you want to sell a car for 200 pieces of paper.

Comment: You mention "namespace n" in the title but never explain what that means. Did you want to remove all elements in the SplitAndMerge namespace?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sxi="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sxi:Messages">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sxi:Message1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template copies everything, and the other two templates skip the `sxi:Messages` and `xsi:Message1` elements - still copying their content.

If you want to remove all elements in the `http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge` namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sxi="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sxi:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: First stylesheet: (a) this will remove `<sxi:Message>` elements that are descendants of `<ZDetails>`, if any exist, contrary to the OP's request; (b) the last two templates can be combined using `match="sxi:Message | sxi:Message1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way, that's guaranteed not to change anything under the `<ZDetails>` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/ZDetails" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template simply copies the `<ZDetails>` element that is a grandchild of the outermost element, along with its entire subtree, and ignores anything else.

Comment: This addresses the requirement expressed in your question, but I'm not sure whether it's really what you meant, because your title suggests a different requirement.